# How to create facet heatmap ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a load of genomic data as follows:

```
chr   leftPos   Sample1    AnotherSample  EtcSample
1     4324       434          43           33
1     5353       63           34           532
1     6632       543          3544         23
2     1443       25           345          543
2     7644       74           26           324
2     8886       23           9            23
3     1287       643          45           23
3     5443       93           23           77
3     7668       33           45           33
```

I would like to create a heatmap organised by chromosome with sample along the x-axis and leftPos along the Y axis. I think this would look good in a facet_wrap image (organised by chromosome) but this means I have to use heatmaps in ggplots and I understand this isn't a thing so I have to use geom_tiles().

So I tried googling all over the place but I'm stuck with how to firstly do a heatmap per chromosome and secondly do tiles per sample. All the examples seem to just use two columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(chr=c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
                 leftPos=c(4324, 5353, 6632, 1443, 7644, 8886, 1287, 5443, 7668),
                 Sample1=c(434,63,543,25,74,23,643,93,33),
                 AnotherSample=c(43,34,3544,345,26,9,45,23,45),
                 EtcSample=c(33,532,23,543,324,23,23,77,33))
```

Reshape your data in a long format.

```
df.l <- reshape(df, 
                varying = c("Sample1", "AnotherSample", "EtcSample"),
                idvar="chr",
                v.names = "value",
                timevar = "sample",
                times=c("Sample1", "AnotherSample", "EtcSample"),
                new.row.names=c(1:(3*nrow(df))),
                direction = "long")

> df.l 
   chr leftPos        sample value
1    1    4324       Sample1   434
2    1    5353       Sample1    63
3    1    6632       Sample1   543
4    2    1443       Sample1    25
5    2    7644       Sample1    74
...
12   1    6632 AnotherSample  3544
13   2    1443 AnotherSample   345
14   2    7644 AnotherSample    26
15   2    8886 AnotherSample     9
16   3    1287 AnotherSample    45
...
23   2    7644     EtcSample   324
24   2    8886     EtcSample    23
25   3    1287     EtcSample    23
26   3    5443     EtcSample    77
27   3    7668     EtcSample    33
```

For representation purpose based on your data, I converted `leftPos` into factor.

```
library(ggplot2)
df.l$leftPos <- factor(df.l$leftPos)
ggplot(df.l, aes(sample, leftPos)) + geom_tile(aes(fill = value)) + 
scale_fill_gradient(low = "white", high = "red") + facet_wrap(~chr)+ 
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: OK. Thanks. So I actually have about 200 samples all of which start with ZS. On the varying line can I use instead varying = HMapSamp[grep("ZS", names(HMapSamp)), ] to capture all these?

Comment: The `varying` argument just needs to be a vector of column names.

Comment: OK. I get the error non-unique values when setting 'row.names':

Comment: Just try to remove the `new.row.names` argument. If it doesn't work, the new number of rows you will have is equal to the number of samples times the number of rows of the inital dataframe. It means you need to replace the 3 in `new.row.names=c(1:(3*nrow(df)))` by the number of samples you need to reshape. In your case about 200.